# Scala yield in case of success, but don't in case of exception

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, yield

I have a Seq[T] in Scala, and want to do something with each element. In case of success, I want to yield the result to the Seq created with for comprehension, but I don't want to yield anything in case of exception.

I want something like this:

```
val destinations = for(path <- files) {
  try {
    yield tryReadDestinations(path) 
  } catch {
    case _ => log.error("Error happened :(")
  }
}
```

But of course code like this does not compile. How can I achieve something like this?

UPDATE:

I managed to get something like this:

```
files
  .map(a => tryExtractDestinationsFromAttachment(a))
  .filter {
    case Success(d) => true
    case Failure(_) => false
  }
  .map(t => t.get)
  .flatten
```

tryExtractDestinationsFromAttachment returns `Try[String]`

But I believe it's possible to make it simplier/more readable?

Comment: What result do you expect? In case of success a collection of results and in case of failure at any point, the cause of it? (all or nothing)?

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap each read in a `Try` and do something like:

```
files
    .map(f => Try(tryReadDestinations(f)))
    .map(t => t.recoverWith { case ex => log.error(ex); t })
    .flatMap(_.toOption)
```

Comment: I don't want to ignore errors, as I need to log them.

Comment: You could `flatMap` the `Seq` to `Either`, where the `left` result was the exception thrown and the `right` result was the normal value.

Comment: It would make sense to introduce a view or an iterator, so that the collection didn't get traversed three times.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def extractDestinationsFromAttachment(path: Path): Seq[Destination] = ???

val destinations = files flatMap { path =>
  Try(extractDestinationsFromAttachment(path)) match {
    case Success(dests) => dests
    case Failure(exception) => { log(exception); Nil }
  }
}
```

All `extractDestinationsFromAttachment` has to do is throw an exception with an error message if it fails, or a `Seq` of destinations if it succeeds.